# How do you reference a dissertation that is turned into a book?

Tags: publications, thesis, self-plagiarism

I recently reconfigured my dissertation to publish as a book.  How do you properly cite, reference, or acknowledge the original dissertation (or is that even necessary)? I obviously want to avoid self-plagiarism, but also think it is silly to cite my dissertation at the end of every paragraph in the book.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What do other similar books in your field do?

Comment: In my field (in which publications are normally in the form of journal articles), a dissertation is treated more like a preprint (or a collection of preprints) and not an independent formally published work. In my understanding, citing the earlier preprint version of the article is not necessary. At most the relationship between the two versions might be noted in the acknowledgement.

Comment: Related question: [How to avoid self-plagiarism when adapting dissertation into a paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46022/how-to-avoid-self-plagiarism-when-adapting-dissertation-into-a-paper).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you still hold copyright to the dissertation, it is enough to say, perhaps in the forward to the book, that it draws heavily from the dissertation including long passages taken directly from it, giving a citation to the dissertation.

The important thing is that a researcher is pointed to the original work to get complete context on the ideas including what you don't put in the book.

It is much harder if you have given copyright to someone else, the university or a publisher. Then it isn't a question of plagiarism but of copyright infringement. But some publishers who hold the copyright might permit such things if asked.